# How to reset personalization for a component after certain number of session or visits?

Tags: personalization, goals, interaction

I have a component on my page which is personalized to show User registration link  when user hits a specific goal.
But Since I do not want to force this on end users so I need end users to see that registration link for the next 3 sessions or visits and then it should be reset to default content.

Is it possible to achieve this with Sitecore's OOTB rules? If yes, an example would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the rule `where the visit no. compares to number`. 
Here you can set the number of visits for which the component will be visible for the user.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, Sitecore will process action rules in a top-down order. So something like 1) this answer -> show default 2) goal trigger -> show user sign up 3) default -> show default

Comment: I guess he want to count the visit after hitting the first personalization.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat You are absolutely correct. I want to count the visit after hitting the first personalization. Will the above solution provided by SumitUpadhyay works in that case?

Comment: No, I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research, I found that this is doable with the right combination of "Number of Elapsed days" and "Past number of Interactions". And Ideally, this should work OOTB but there is a bug in Sitecore that does not evaluate these two parameters in a way they are supposed to.

Fortunately, I found a hotfix(via Googling) that make it to work. The hotfix number is: **Sitecore.Support.129513**

After implementing this, I tried the below rule which evaluates if the goal was triggered in last 7 days and user has visited the site 3 times after the goal was hit.

> where the MyGoal1 goal was triggered during a past or current interaction and when the number of elapsed days is less than or equal to 7 and when the past number of interactions is greater than or equal to 3.

The solution works as expected.